# ApexCharts: radar chart data from mysql

Tags: apexcharts

Is there any way to fill series, name and data from ajax request? Or may be any way to generate 'options' property of Apex Chart?

Comment: Ya, you call the ajax request and provide the success callback (function). In the success callback, you provide the response data to the chart options and render the chart.

Comment: https://apexcharts.com/docs/update-charts-from-json-api-ajax/ Here's a tip for updating one series, but how to update multiple series?

Comment: Would be great if you could provide a sample response, and sample chart (configuration) that you want to be rendered. Meanwhile, in the link you shared, the `updateSeries` method requires an array argument. You can provide multiple series to the `updateSeries`. `chart.updateSeries([{/* Series 1 */}, {/* Series 2 */}, ...]);`